# XCodeproj empty after cloning from Git

Tags: ios, git, swift, github, clone

I have an Swift project that utilizes two libraries: the SQLite and SwiftCSV project. They can be found on: `https://github.com/stephencelis/SQLite.swift` and `https://github.com/naoty/SwiftCSV` respectively. I followed the instructions on each respective Github README to incorporate the projects into my project which works fine, but when I push my project to Github and I have another teammate of mine clone the project, the `SwiftCSV` and `SQLite` projects turn up empty so my teammate has to re-add them into his project. I have been trying to google different responses but maybe I am looking for the wrong keywords. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should (and may be) adding the above projects to your repo as [submodules](http://www.git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules) (if not, [read up on them](http://www.git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules)).

If you used submodules, they are not automatically checked out when you clone a repository. You can, however, use `clone`'s `--recursive` flag to ensure submodules are checked out when someone first clones your project:

```
git clone --recursive git@github.com:your/project.git
```

If the project has already been cloned, one can check out the submodules by running the following incantation from within their project directory:

```
git submodule update --init
```

> *Note:* Xcode is usually smart about letting you check out submodules from within Xcode itself. Check the **Source Control** menu and see if **SQLite.swift** or **SwiftCSV** show up under **Working Copies**.

If you merely downloaded the projects and dragged them into your Xcode project (rather than use submodules, as instructed above), they'll likely be referencing directories *outside of your project*. Make sure you move them to your project's directory *before* dragging them into your Xcode project. If you don't, the projects will appear red/unavailable on subsequent clones.

Comment: This made a lot of sense. Thank you so much for this!

Answer (score 0):

usually, xcodeproj is in gitignore, please remove it from .gitignore file

Comment: Hi, I have the following in my .gitignore. Should I take all of these out?

Project.xcodeproj/project.xcworkspace/xcuser*
Project.xcodeproj/project.xcworkspace/xcuserdata/*
Project.xcodeproj/project.xcworkspace/xcshareddata/*
Project.xcodeproj/project.xcworkspace/xcuserdata/schan93.xcuserdatad/UserInterfaceState.xcuserstate
Project.xcodeproj/xcuserdata/*

Comment: I tried to uncomment the above comments in my .gitignore and it didn't seem to fix anything.